# Is there a generating function for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, integer-partitions

The sequence is:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 18, 25, 35, 50, 69, 93, 126, 167, 220, 290, 377, 486, 627, 800, 1017, 1290, 1623, 2032, 2542, 3161, 3917, 4843,...

It is related to partitions of $n$.  It is a subsequence of a sequence that has the generating function:

$$G(t,x) = \prod_{i>=1} \dfrac{1 - x^{prime(i)}}{(1 - x^i)\cdot(1 - tx^{prime(i)})}$$

That triangle has row lengths 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,...  If we start with row and column indices of zero, my sequence is formed by taking the $n$th element from the $3n$th row in that triangle.

I don't know what other information might be necessary to answer the question, so ask if needed.

EDIT:

My sequence in now https://oeis.org/A299731.  If the answer to my question is in the affirmative the generating function can be added to A299731, or I will add it and link to this question, so that the answerer gets the credit.

Comment: So is the nth element of the sequence $[x^n t^{3n}]G(t, x)$ or $[x^{3n} t^n]G(t, x)$?

Comment: The G.f. above is from https://oeis.org/A222656. My sequence takes elements 0, 5, 14, 28, 46, 69, 96, 128, 164, 205, 250, 300, 354, 413, 476, 544, 616, 693, 774, 860, 950, 1045, 1144, 1248, 1356, 1469, 1586, ... (floor((3n)^2 / 4) - 2*n, n>=1)  from A222656.